# Issues with writing .js function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having issues with the following .js function.  The console log is giving me the following error:

> "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",

For the line:   degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);

I'm not seeing where another ")" should be entered - thanks for your help.

```js
function convertToCentigrade (degFahren) {
 var degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren -32);
  return degCent;
}

var degFahren = [212, 32, -459.15];
var degCent = [];
var loopCounter;

for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=2; loopCounter ++) {
 degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);
}

for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter--) {
 document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheight ");
 document.write("which is " + degCent[loopCounter] + " degrees Centigrade<br />");
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` in your first `document.write`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
    document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheight ");
```

You need a + after "was"

Comment: Please consider commenting and/or voting to close next time. *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error.*** You can see additional discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a plus sign after "was"

```js
function convertToCentigrade (degFahren) {
 var degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren -32);
  return degCent;
}

var degFahren = [212, 32, -459.15];
var degCent = [];
var loopCounter;

for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=2; loopCounter++) {
 degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);
}

for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter--) {
 document.write ("Value " + loopCounter + " was " +  degFahren[loopCounter] + " degrees Fahrenheight ");
 document.write("which is " + degCent[loopCounter] + " degrees Centigrade<br />");
}
```